# How to style a tablelayout in android

Tags: android, coding-style, tablelayout

Can anyone tell me how to add a boarder to a TableLayout in android, like the one below?

http://developer.android.com/images/table_layout.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table layout don't display the use border use view control

```
<View android:id="@+id/View01" android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@color/blue_text"></View>
```

for vertical line give width

Answer (score 0):

TableLayout containers do not display border lines for their rows, columns, or cells. You cannot add border to table layout cells which is mentioned in the [TableLayout Javadoc](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.1_r1_src/android/widget/TableLayout.html).