# Android - Styling TableLayout

Tags: android, android-styles, android-tablelayout

Is there a way to style a `TableLayout` entirely ?

I found [this] but I wondering if there was a way to apply the style to the table and not to the rows individually. I have a lot of tables and I don't want to apply style individually to each row.

I tried to apply a style to the `TableLayout` but the `style` tag in XML doesn't have an `android:tablerow` `item`.

It would be ideal if I could do something like this:

```
<style name="Table" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:tablerow">@style/TableRow</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Did you look at this post? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862136/how-to-style-a-tablelayout-in-android

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question

Comment: I'm looking for the same! Were you able to find a way to style it this way or did you have to copy paste for each TableRow?

Comment: This was a really long time ago so I don't recall... sorry.