# TableLayout border issue Android

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a table that has a border around each of the table rows. I get a problem with the border part when text in one column goes onto a second line, while the text in the other column doesn't. That causes the row that doesn't have the text wrapped onto a second line to be be shorter and a black background on the second line. How can I get that row to be the same height as the other row?

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#013567" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#013567"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="long text abc 123 ong tex ong tex"
            android:textColor="#fff" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#013567"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="short text"
            android:textColor="#fff" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#013567"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="short text"
            android:textColor="#fff" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#013567"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="long text abc 123 ong tex ong tex"
            android:textColor="#fff" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/EMk3d.png
Sorry I tried to add it earlier, but I couldn't for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add following properties to your `TextView`, not your `TableRow`:

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`

or

`android:layout_height="fill_parent"` (deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following to your `TableRow`:

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

add new line to the en of 'short text'

programmatically:

- `\n`

xml:

- simply hit enter in your XML code

Comment: But then on landscape and larger screens the other text short text box is larger.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways to fix this,

add a FrameLayout around each text with `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

or

change your stying to be applied to the table, as e.g.

[How to style a tablelayout in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862136/how-to-style-a-tablelayout-in-android)

setting the Table background to be the blue and borders to be black.

Comment: When I tried adding a frame layout that didn't work for me, but the other link you gave me helped (removed a few lines of code that I didn't need)!

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned, that is the better way in most situations as the styling is on the table rather than the text.